# C++ find words ending with "ing" and are less than or equal to 10 characters

Tags: c++, visual-c++

As the title suggests I want to find all the words in my vector that meet this rule.

My current code is:

```
void Dictionary::endingIng() {
string findIng;
string foundIng;
int sevenLetters = 7;
for (Word findIng : deffinitions)
    if (findIng.getWord().find("ing") <= sevenLetters) {
        foundIng = findIng.getWord();
        cout << foundIng << endl;
    }
```

However, it also returns words that either contain "ing" somewhere in the middle and words longer then 10 characters, some examples being:

```
accordingly
barringout
bingo
commandingly
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does Word::find() return the number of letters?

Comment: Be a dang peculiar find function if it did. Mac, is this is hand-wave and magic happens code or are we supposed to infer actual coded capabilities from this?

Comment: Most likely it is the same as [`str::find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

Comment: I would just suggest you watch out for the variable shadowing that occurs in your for loop. You declare `string findIng` but then your for loop re-declares it as `Word findIng` this may cause unexpected behavior later on

Comment: Three part pop quiz: 1) given that the size of a string `s` can be obtained as `s.size()`, how do you get the index of the third last character of the string, 2) how do you extract a given substring of a string?  3) how do you compare one string to another. Simply answer these ridiculously simple questions, and you will have the answer to your own question, too!

Comment: Small note for the two current answers: using find() this way is OK for small strings such as words, but you don't want to use the same technique for long sentences. Just getting a string of the last 3 characters and comparing or using a regular expression that includes a final `$` (matching end-of-input - sort of) is much more efficient. Currently those answers are searching the entire string for something you *know* should be at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this can help.
Adding a case to skip words more than 10 letters.

Also checking the position of "ing" for words <= 10 letters.

Uses `rfind` for edge case like `"inginging"`

```
for (Word findIng : deffinitions) {
   std::string word = findIng.getWord();
   if (word.length() > 10) {
      // skip this - word is more than 10 letters including "ing"
      continue;
   }

   size_t pos = word.rfind("ing");
   if (pos == word.length() - 3) {
      // we got a match "ing" as suffix of this word
      // do something with `word`
   }
}
```

Comment: It should be smaller or equal to 10, so 7 *including* "ing". I'd just use 10.

Comment: ha! used `rfind` for that. :D

Comment: Looks defffinitely OK now, I'll stop ringing.

Comment: by the `deffinition` of OK. thanks for helping me improve this answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your help everyone, I'll have a go using this code. I should have mentioned that I'm relatively new to C++ coming form Python, so I sometimes I may not quite understand or know what is the best way to do something. Most of my learning is just through seeing what works and what doesn't. Thanks again.

Comment: @BenVoigt, updated. thank you for pointing out and helping me improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you (using your current solution) check the length, then get the last 3 values and check if they match.

Or you can go

```
CString findString = "ing";
int maxLetters = findString.GetLength() + 7; //magic number

foreach(CString s in dictionary)
{        
    bool b_SmallEnough = (s.Find(findString) <= maxLetters );
    bool b_EndsIn = (s.ReverseFind(findString) == (s.GetLength() - findString.GetLength()); //reverse find so it doesn't get the first "ing in bringing and return false because 2 != 5
    if(b_SmallEnough && b_EndsIn)
    {
        std::wcout << s << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, bool b_EndsIn could be:

```
bool b_EndsIn = (s.MakeReverse.Find(findString.MakeReverse()) == 0);
```

This will mean that your're checking the end first, and always getting the last match